# Tengo varios radio buttons y necesito que la opción que marque se imprima en un text área

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

las opciones se repiten las veces que se haga click y no deberia, si es del mismo grupo se reemplaza y si no se añade, ademas, ¿sera que se pueden orgnizar lo que aparece en el textarea segun yo lo decida?

```js
function addText(text){

      var actualText = $('#notem').val();
      var newText = actualText + " " +text;
      $('#notem').val(newText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              FUTBOL
                  <br>
                  SI<input type="radio" name="futbol" id="r1" value="" onclick="addText('SI PRATICARIA FUTBOL')">
                  NO<input type="radio" name="futbol" id="r2" value="" onclick="addText('NO PRACTICARIA FUTBOL, ')">
                  <br><br>
              NATACION
                  <br>
                  SI<input type="radio" name="natacion" id="r3" value="" onclick="addText('SI PRATICARIA NATACION, ')">
                  NO<input type="radio" name="natacion" id="r4" value="" onclick="addText('NO PRATICARIAC NATACION, ')">
                  <br><br>
              CICLISMO
                  <br>
                  SI<input type="radio" name="ciclismo" id="r5" onclick="addText('SI PRACTICARIA CICLISMO, ')">
                  NO<input type="radio" name="ciclismo" id="r6" onclick="addText('NO PRACTICARIA CICLISMO, ')">
                  <br><br>
              LE GUSTARIA PRATICAR OTRO DEPORTE
                  <br>
                  SI<input type="radio" name="siotro" id="r7" onclick="addText('SI PRACTICARIA OTRO')">
                  NO<input type="radio" name="nootro"id="r8" onclick="addText('NO PRACTICARIA OTRO')">
                  <br>
                  <textarea id="notem" readonly style="width:170px; height:130px;"></textarea>
```

Esto suceda sin borrar la anterior mientas pertenezca a un grupo diferente de radio buttons porque si es de mismo grupo que la reemplace.

Comment: Hola @Juan y bienvenido stackoverflow.  por favor puedes editar tu pregunta y colocar el código que tienes desarrollado hasta ahora y cual es el error que se te genera para poderte ayudar mejor. Gracias

Comment: Hola @Yoel muchas gracias! ya añadi un poco de codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes colocar los textos en los `value` de los radios y como veo que estas usando jquery, puedes obtener todos los radios en una variable con `$('input[type="radio"]')` y asginarles un evento, cuando se haga click en alguno, que se obtengan todos los values de los radios que esten marcados para colocar el texto en el textarea:

```js
var todos = $('input[type="radio"]');
  $(todos).on('click',() =>{
    var newText = '';
    Array.from(todos).forEach(
      function(element) {
        if(element.checked)
          newText+=element.value
      });
    $('#notem').val(newText);
  });
```

```html
FUTBOL
<br>
SI<input type="radio" name="futbol" id="r1" value='SI PRATICARIA FUTBOL, '>
NO<input type="radio" name="futbol" id="r2" value='NO PRACTICARIA FUTBOL, '>
<br><br>
NATACION
<br>
SI<input type="radio" name="natacion" id="r3" value='SI PRATICARIA NATACION, '>
NO<input type="radio" name="natacion" id="r4" value='NO PRATICARIA NATACION, '>
<br><br>
CICLISMO
<br>
SI<input type="radio" name="ciclismo" id="r5" value='SI PRACTICARIA CICLISMO, '>
NO<input type="radio" name="ciclismo" id="r6" value='NO PRACTICARIA CICLISMO, '>
<br><br>
LE GUSTARIA PRATICAR OTRO DEPORTE
<br>
SI<input type="radio" name="otrod" id="r7" value='SI PRACTICARIA OTRO'>
NO<input type="radio" name="otrod" id="r8" value='NO PRACTICARIA OTRO'>
<br>
<textarea id="notem" readonly style="width:170px; height:130px;"></textarea>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Luego para que los textos se muestren en el orden en que se marcan se pude guardar en un `Set` de modo que no se repetiran y los vas agregando y removiendo conforme se van marcando:

```js
const textos = new Set(); 

var todos = $('input[type="radio"]');
  $(todos).on('click',() =>{
    var newText = '';
    Array.from(todos).forEach(
      function(element) {
        if(element.checked)
          textos.add(element.value)
        else
          textos.delete(element.value)
      });
      newText=Array.from(textos).join('');
    $('#notem').val(newText);
  });
```

```html
FUTBOL
<br>
SI<input type="radio" name="futbol" id="r1" value='SI PRATICARIA FUTBOL, '>
NO<input type="radio" name="futbol" id="r2" value='NO PRACTICARIA FUTBOL, '>
<br><br>
NATACION
<br>
SI<input type="radio" name="natacion" id="r3" value='SI PRATICARIA NATACION, '>
NO<input type="radio" name="natacion" id="r4" value='NO PRATICARIA NATACION, '>
<br><br>
CICLISMO
<br>
SI<input type="radio" name="ciclismo" id="r5" value='SI PRACTICARIA CICLISMO, '>
NO<input type="radio" name="ciclismo" id="r6" value='NO PRACTICARIA CICLISMO, '>
<br><br>
LE GUSTARIA PRATICAR OTRO DEPORTE
<br>
SI<input type="radio" name="otrod" id="r7" value='SI PRACTICARIA OTRO'>
NO<input type="radio" name="otrod" id="r8" value='NO PRACTICARIA OTRO'>
<br>
<textarea id="notem" readonly style="width:170px; height:130px;"></textarea>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda me funciono ahora solo falta que yo marque cuál quier respuesta del cuestionario y aun así me conserve un orden

Comment: Hola, a que te refieres con el orden? osea el orden en que los marcas? no es por el orden del formulario? en ese caso habria que guardar los id en un array.

Comment: Me refiero a que yo puedo contestarlos en cualquier orden pero me gustaría generar una nota donde se ordenen cómo yo quisiera en realidad.. lo que había pensado era hacerlo por medio de imprimir cada repuesta en una etiqueta p y así guardar una posición y luego por medio de un button con evento onclick ordenarlos en el text área

Comment: @JuanDavidLosada no entiendo bien lo que buscas, en que forma quieres que se reordenen los textos?

Comment: Ósea la penúltima opción que tengo en mi form es ciclismo pero si yo quisiera que al ser impresa en el textarea apareciera de primera y futbol de segunda... y así sucesivamente pero sin perder el orden en el form

Comment: @JuanDavidLosada si lo quieres en orden en que se van marcando eso se puede hacer, dame un momento.

Comment: Vale... disculpa molestar tanto pero resolviendo eso prácticamente terminaría el proyecto y hasta podría agregar más preguntas con radio buttons y arreglar su orden al imprimir como yo quiera.. y algo más y si una las preguntas se responde con un input type text, como pródria agregarlo al textarea?

Comment: @JuanDavidLosada ya actualize la respuesta, y para agregar el texto del input, le pones un id y obtienes lo que escriban dentro con `$('#id_del_input').val();`, esa es toda la ayuda que te puedo dar, marca la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvio por favor.